# Why does the "expected" line varies with the unknown new physics parameter on Brazil-band plots?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, beyond-the-standard-model

There are two similar questions here, but they could not help me (I could not relate their answers to my problem, at least). I hope that I can make myself clear in the following.

Take, for instance, the fig. 6 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12783.pdf).

In the horizontal we have the unknown parameter being studied, an exotic neutral vector boson's mass, and in the vertical we have cross sections.

Now, the red line represents the (total) signal prediction: it is simulated in points of the space of parameters with different masses and, obviously, varies with it.

What I don't understand is why the expected (and observed) limit cross sections also change with the new mass. That is, if I come close to understand this figures correctly, the "expected" and "observed" contours are paired with the null hypothesis which could be, for instance, the Standard Model, being the current theory and one which does not contain the new physics related to the unknown parameter. That is, they are the background.

I understand that these are limits of cross sections for each mass such that if the signal is greater than it, than that point may be excluded in an experiment with a confidence level of 95%, and that distributions with respect to some strategically chosen observable, which offers the best resolution between signal and background, are used in applying statistics, and that this should be the origin of the changing "minimum number of signal events for 95% confidence exclusion".

But at this point (when calculating the expected curve) all we know is the background! We know the shape of the background distribution (both expected and observed), but not the signal one. If we knew exactly how the signal shape scales with increasing cross section, then we could indeed conclude what minimum number of events (or, equivalently, cross section) is necessary for a 95% confidence level with relation to the background for each mass, but I don't see how we could.

Is a shape for the signal simply assumed (to be, for instance, a peak in some invariant mass)?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://amva4newphysics.wordpress.com/2016/12/15/brazil-bands-what-are-they/#more-18611. You say :"all we know is the background!" in the plot there is also the signal calculated, with the red line that is way off the observed.

Comment: @annav Thank you for the comment! I have indeed already read that post. I understand that the signal is also calculated and is the red line. What I fail to see is how the expected/observed line varies with the exotic mass. I mean, they should be simply a number (the cross section without new physics/measured cross section). Unless these curves, the expected/observed ones, contain themselves information about the signal distribution on some observable.

Comment: The expected mass , lets take Higgs to gamma gamma, depends on the invariant mass of the gamma gamma. For other decay modes it will be the invariant mass of the modes looked at.  In your figure six, it is more convoluted, the  standard model will produce the dileptons , i.e enough leptons that another model could consider a signal., and the "observed " line  says how many such events exist that could be interpreted as new Z , and see if the number fits the red line of a  new Z as they want existing at that mass. It does not, except where the lines cross, but since nothing is seen for two sigma

Comment: there is small hope to see it with higher statistics

Comment: @annav It seems like what you are saying is what was my impression. What I don't get is the following: to derive this limit number of events with 95% c.l., they would have to know the shape of the distribution to feed signal and background to a statistics (Poisson, most likely, since there are few events). I don't understand how can it simply be assumed that the signal distribution will be a peak at the invariant mass of the decay product of the new particle. Obviously that is expected for resonances but it seems far too simplistic to be always done.

Comment: The shape of the distribution of resonances is  given by  quantum mechanics, a breit wigner curve that enters in the propagator of the Feynmn diagram describing the decay. see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit%E2%80%93Wigner_distribution

Comment: @annav Ok, I think this is what I needed to hear. So, in this kind of plot, the narrow width approximation is always assumed with a Breit Wigner distribution (centered at the scanned mass) on the invariant mass of the product of the decay?

Comment: yes,  that is the standard I believe. as if the sought particle existed.